# Swift - Animation when expanding Table View Cell by tap

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, cell, expand

I have Table View with custom cell, which contains some text and another Table View with custom cell (just two labels on it).
I implemented expanding cell by selecting. Just set height:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let game = games[indexPath.row] as Game //Game for cell

    if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row {
        if cellTapped == false {
            cellTapped = true
            return 50 + 30*CGFloat(game.getNumberOfPlayers())
        } else {
            cellTapped = false
            return 50
        }
    }
    return 50
}
```

Example of screen with expanding cells:
[image]

Custom cell with labels:
[image: Custom cell with labels]

Everything works fine, but when I expand top level cell first time, **all controls from internal table cells move from left to right** till they take place according to constraints. If I collapse and expand cell again, there is no animation for labels.
How to disable this 'first time expand' behavior?

Thanks in advance!